# General::munfl: - too small to represent as a normalized machine number error

Tags: numerics, warning-messages

I've been working on this code and finally got it to a point where it produces something.

But there seems to be an underflow problem.

I believe this happens when Exp[] is used and tried to fix it to no avail.

Could somebody take a look at this? How do I get rid of the error - if possible? Thanks...

````
In[42]:= ClearAll["Global'*"]

In[43]:= Psc[x_, k1_, \[Delta]1_] := 
  If[x <= k1, 0, k1 - x] + \[Delta]1;

In[44]:= Psp[x_, k2_, d2_] := If[x >= k2, 0, x - k2] + d2;

In[45]:= BisecBSV[PutCall_, S_, K_, r_, T_, a_, b_, realC_] :=
  Module[
   {TOL, lowCdif, highCdif, test, midP, cnt, midCdif, aa, bb},
   TOL = 0.00001;
   lowCdif = realC - BSprice[S, K, r, T, a, PutCall];
   highCdif = realC - BSprice[S, K, r, T, b, PutCall];
   aa = a;
   bb = b;
   If[(lowCdif * highCdif > 0),
    midP = -1,
    For[cnt = 1, cnt <= 1000, cnt++,
      midP = (aa + bb)/2;
      midCdif = realC - BSprice[S, K, r, T, midP, PutCall];
      If[Abs[midCdif] < TOL,
       Break[]];
      If[midCdif > 0,
       aa = midP,
       bb = midP;]
      ];
    ];
   Return[midP];
   ];

In[46]:= BSprice[S_, K_, r_, T_, v_, PutCall_] :=
  Module[{d, bscall},
   bscall = SetPrecision[0.0, Infinity];
   d = (Log[S/K] + T*(r + 0.5*v^2))/(v*Sqrt[T]);
   bscall = S*Gauss[d] - Exp[-r*T]*K*Gauss[d - v*Sqrt[T]];
   If[PutCall == "Call",
    Return[bscall],
    Return[bscall - S + K*Exp[-r*T]];
    ];
   ];

In[47]:= NormSDist[x_] :=
  With[{
    b1 = 0.31938153,
    b2 = -0.356563782,
    b3 = 1.781477937,
    b4 = -1.821255978,
    b5 = 1.330274429,
    p = 0.2316419,
    c = 0.39894228},
   With[{aux = Function[{t},
       c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5 + b4) + b3) + b2) + b1)]},
    If[x >= 0,
     1.0 - aux[1.0/(1.0 + p*x)],
     aux[1.0/(1.0 - p*x)]]]];



In[48]:= Gauss[x_] := NormSDist[x];

In[49]:= Manipulate[
 Plot[{(Psp[x, k2, \[Delta]2] + 
     Psc[x, k1, \[Delta]1]), -(BSprice[x, k1, r, T/365, 
        BisecBSV["Call", k1, k2, r, T/365, 0.01, 100, 
         BSprice[k1, k2, r, T/365, \[Sigma]1, "Call"]], "Call"] + 
       BSprice[x, k2, r, T/365, 
        BisecBSV["Put", k1, k2, r, T/365, 0.01, 100, 
         BSprice[k1, k2, r, T/365, \[Sigma]2, "Put"]], 
        "Put"]) + \[Delta]1 + \[Delta]2}, {x, 200, 500}, 
  PlotRange -> {{200, 500}, {5, -20}}, PlotLabel -> "DIA", 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Magenta, Thick}}], {{k1, 350}, 0, 600,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Delta]1, 0.59}, 0, 30, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k2, 275}, 0, 600, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Delta]2, 0.12}, 0, 30, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 0.02}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 0.0}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Sigma]1, 0.1515}, 0, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Sigma]2, 0.2811}, 0, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{T, 30}, 0.0000001, 60, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Out[49]= Manipulate[Plot[{Psp[x, k2, \[Delta]2] + Psc[x, k1, \
\[Delta]1], 
    -(BSprice[x, k1, r, T/365, BisecBSV["Call", k1, k2, r, T/365, \
0.01, 100, 
         BSprice[k1, k2, r, T/365, \[Sigma]1, "Call"]], "Call"] + 
       BSprice[x, k2, r, T/365, BisecBSV["Put", k1, k2, r, T/365, \
0.01, 100, 
         BSprice[k1, k2, r, T/365, \[Sigma]2, "Put"]], "Put"]) + \
\[Delta]1 + \[Delta]2}, 
   {x, 200, 500}, PlotRange -> {{200, 500}, {5, -20}}, PlotLabel -> \
"DIA", 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Magenta, Thick}}], 
  {{k1, 350}, 0, 600, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{\[Delta]1, 0.59}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{k2, 275}, 0, 600, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{\[Delta]2, 0.12}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{r, 0.02}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{d, 0.}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Sigma]1, 0.1515}, 0, \
5, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Sigma]2, 0.2811}, 0, 5, Appearance \
-> "Labeled"}, 
  {{T, 31.5}, 1.*^-7, 60, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

General::munfl: Exp[-3586.53] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-3586.29] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-3586.53] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-2255.28] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2255.04] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2255.28] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-1933.93] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-1933.68] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-1933.93] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-2070.36] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2070.12] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2070.36] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-2396.84] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2396.6] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-2396.84] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-5008.3] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-5008.06] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-5008.3] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-6682.22] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-6681.98] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-6682.22] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-10662.5] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-10662.2] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-10662.5] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-19346.6] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-19346.4] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-19346.6] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-39359.6] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-39359.4] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-39359.6] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-4.6244*10^9] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-4.6244*10^9] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-1.0614*10^12] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

General::munfl: Exp[-3418.06] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-3417.82] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-3418.06] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use something like `cExp` below instead of `Exp`.

```
cExp = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   If[x < -300., 0., Exp[x]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much...

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You could use `Log[$MinMachineNumber]` as the lower bound before setting to zero.

Comment: Why not just use `Exp[x]` and let it underflow? No error in generated in the WVM. But `Quiet@Exp[#]&` seems even better maybe.